# How to call one tcl script by other script and pass argument?

Tags: scripting, command, tcl, exec, puts

I would like to call one TCL script inside the other?
I tried the following command:

```
exec tclsh print.tcl
```

Inside of print.tcl is written:

```
puts "Second script"
```

The program runs without any errors but does not show any output.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That value would be obtained via:

```
set output [exec tclsh print.tcl]
puts "The output was: $output"
```

If you want it to go directly to the user, you need to do a bit of redirection:

```
exec tclsh print.tcl >@stdout
```

or possibly even this (if the script prints errors that you don't want to capture):

```
exec tclsh print.tcl >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

On POSIX systems (i.e., not Windows), you can even send the output to the user *and* capture it in the calling script at the same time:

```
set output [exec tclsh print.tcl | tee /dev/tty]
puts "The output was: $output"
```

Comment: It does not work. It shows the bellow message:
couldn't execute "print.tcl": no such file or directory

But the print.tcl file is exist

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, the 2nd script is a Tcl script, so you could do

```
source print.tcl
```

which will do what you want, I think.

---

Since the print script needs `argv`, you need to set that in the current script:

```
set argv [list foo bar baz]
source print.tcl
```

---

and if you're invoking source from within a procedure, you'll probably want to execute the print code at the top-level scope, not the procedure scope

```
proc myProc {} {
    set ::argv [list foo bar baz]
    uplevel #0 {source print.tcl}
}
myProc
```

Comment: With this, I have a little problem. How can I pass an argument to the script with argv?
 This one shows error